# InetAddress not able to retrieve FQDN while nslookup is able to

Tags: java, ldap, dns

I am trying to retrieve a FQDN of a specific computer from the DNS but on my environment when I use `nslookup` on the hostname I get its FQDN but when I try this code in Java I only get the host name back:

`InetAddress.getByName("Host name or address").getCanonicalHostName()`

What can be the cause? 
Is there a better method of getting the FQDN from a host name without credentials or connection to the LDAP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with your system configuration.

From Javadoc:

If there is a security manager, this method first calls its checkConnect method with the hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the calling code is allowed to know the hostname for this IP address, i.e., to connect to the host. If the operation is not allowed, it will return the textual representation of the IP address.

[getCanonicalHostName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29)

You could either try to alter system settings to allow for FQDN to be resolved or try to execute ping command, parse it and get hostname out of that.

Comment: Do you know what setting prevents this? something in the DNS? something in the client? Why this setting does not prevent the nslookup finding the FQDN?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (never had a problem with it myself) but i believe this may be able to help: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19534-01/819-3201/gboce/index.html)